# How Cloud SQL node library authenticates over pg connection libraries like npm pg

Tags: google-cloud-sql, node-postgres

Was checking out the new [google node sql connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector) for Cloud SQL.

It tells the authentication mechanism for libraries like [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) as follows.

```
import pg from 'pg';
import {Connector} from '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector';
const {Pool} = pg;

const connector = new Connector();
const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
  instanceConnectionName: 'my-project:region:my-instance',
  type: 'PUBLIC'
});
const pool = new Pool({
  ...clientOpts,
  user: 'my-user',
  password: 'my-password',
  database: 'db-name',
  max: 5
});
const {rows} = await pool.query('SELECT NOW()');
console.table(rows); // prints returned time value from server

await pool.end();
connector.close();
```

On debugging the `connector.getOptions({ instanceConnectionName: 'my-project:region:my-instance', type: 'PUBLIC' });` it seems to return an object of structure, `{ ssl: boolean; stream: StreamFunction; }` and that is passed to the new Pool constructor. But the Client object passed to Pool constructor does not have any parameter called stream in the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/apis/client).

So i am trying to understand how [google node sql connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector) authenticates [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)  to GCP. Want this information since i am trying to use the  [google node sql connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector) to authenticate some other ORM tools in node.

I was expecting `connector.getOptions({ instanceConnectionName: 'my-project:region:my-instance', type: 'PUBLIC' });` to return objects that other libraries already support so that we can use those configs for authentication generically for other libraries.

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72372222/connecting-with-pg-pool-and-gcp-iam-based-database-authentication) & this document on [Connect using Cloud SQL connectors](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors)

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud SQL Node Connector uses [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials). See [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest#choosing-the-correct-credential-type-automatically) for Node specific details.

Feel free to file an issue on the repo if your use case isn't covered.